# IndexOutOfBoundsException why?

Tags: java, sorting

Ok...i am trying to implement my own version of a bin sort, most commonly known as a bucket sort. I run the program and I get a indexOutOfBounds Error. And I don't know why. Can someone please explain why. Please note that the binsort algorithm is not done. Int n is the length of the array, and m is the upper limit of a list generated by a random number generator from 0 to 100.

```
public static void binSort (int []array, int n, int m)
{
//create upperbounds
int x = m / 3;                    //33
int y = n - x;                    //67
int z = n;                        //100

int []temp1 = new int [n-1];
int []temp2 = new int [n-1];
int []temp3 = new int [n-1];

for (int i: array)
{
    if(array[i] < x)
    {
        temp1[i] = array[i];
    }
    else if(array[i] < y)
    {
        temp2[i] = array[i];
    }
    else
    {
        temp3[i] = array[i];     
    }
}

for ( int j = 0; j <= x; j++)
    array[j] = temp1[j];
for ( int k = x + 1; k <= y; k++)
    array[k] = temp2[k];
for ( int l = y + 1; l <= z; l++)
    array[l] = temp3[l];

}
```

Comment: It helps if you post the stacktrace.

Comment: first of all, IndexOutOfBounds is an exception, not an error.  where is the error being thrown?  can you provide the trace?

Comment: i hope you are not naming vars n and m in your production code

Answer (score 5):

There's a slight misuse of the `enhanced for` loop there.

```
for (int i: array)
```

Here, `i` is not the index but an element of `array`. Every time the `for` iterates, it automaticly does this for you:

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    int i= array[index];
```

Long story short, the `for` handles the iteration for you and you just have to use the `i` element.

Answer (score 2):

**-** First mistake

```
  for (int i: array)
```

In the above `for-each` loop, at every iteration, the successive index value of array goes into i. **So i is the value Not index.**

**So array[i] is wrong.**

Use something like this...

```
for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    int i= array[index]
```

**-** Secondly i think in `for ( int j = 0; j <= x; j++)`, it should be `j < x`

Answer (score 0):

`temp3[]` has the size `n-1`. That means that the last element will be at index `n-2`. Since `z = n`, this will be the same as `temp3[z-2]`. However, in your last for-loop `l` will reach the value `z`, which means that `temp3[l]` will throw an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

```
 int z = n;                        //100
 int []temp3 = new int [n-1];      //last element of temp3 will be at tempt3[z-2]
 for ( int l = y + 1; l <= z; l++) //l will iterate from y + 1 to z
   array[l] = temp3[l];     // temp3[l] will throw indexOutOfBounds when z>=l>z-2
```

**EDIT:** Also, as others have already pointed out, `for (int i: array)` might not do what you think it does...